# changing the color of the little popup that comes on mouseover "title"

Tags: html, css

is it possible to change the formatting of the little yellow box that popups on mouseover, the one that is specified with the title attribute?

For example changing the yellow color for the background or the font color.

Thanks,

Comment: Shows up white on other browsers.

Comment: okay white, is it not possible to change the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. As random hints, it's specific to how browsers are implemented. It's intended more for general accessibility purposes. You should look into using JQuery, there are loads of plugins for creating tooltips.

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

There will be plugins that can be configured to automatically use the value you specified in the title attribute for the content of the tooltips.